# How can I replace a PSP's 1004 CMOS battery?

Tags: psp

My PSP CMOS battery is oxidized. It surely is dead because the console won't keep the time and date. This is not a huge problem for me, the real problem is that I suspect the acid to be the reason why the analog pad is being defective. I opened the pad and everything seems fine; all the contacts were cleaned with alcohol. I tried a second pad that works perfectly on another PSP and it behaves the same exact way on mine. The battery is located right next to the pad pins, but on the opposite side of the panel.

When I try to remove the oxidized battery, however, I'm pulling the entire base with it. The console is 11 years old but it works perfectly otherwise. I would like to avoid ruining it.

Is the CMOS battery in the first PSP soldered to the motherboard? Or is it stuck because of the acid and I just have to try harder?

How can I properly replace it?

Comment: Why was this migrated to here?

Comment: An user on Super User suggested me to do so because this site covers "Game-specific hardware and utilities" as a topic, while Super User is not about "video games or consoles"; even though i first though of this as a general hardware issue..

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hardware deconstruction, which is not a gaming specific task.  While we might have some familiarity with how a PSP is put together, your issue isn't with a PSP, but the techniques used to construct it in the first place.

Comment: I already flagged the question asking for a migration. The question was migrated here from Super User as suggested by an other user.

Comment: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ perhaps?

Comment: Agreed with @DJPirtu. The masterminds over at electronics will know a lot more about this than us.

Comment: I've cleaned up the bits that aren't quite on-topic for us, e.g. the bits about how to handle a battery, and I think the end result is on-topic for us. Reopening

Comment: @badp You missed some parts.  The second paragraph on down is still not something we can help with.

Comment: If you take off that part too,the question is practically going to be useless (I mean to answer the question title you have to answer that part). I flagged the question yesterday asking for a second migration to Electronics, maybe it is just better to put the question on hold again until a moderator entervens so I can add back all the details and anyone that is going to search for this will find much more information. What do you think?

Comment: @frank that part is not a question, he's simply explaining what he tried, something we encourage

Comment: @Omar there are two parts to your original question — what sort of mess am I into and how do I get out of it? The first question is on topic for us for the part that concerns the PSP; the second part is interesting if it lets others avoid getting into a mess to begin with. For the other parts I'm indeed afraid that you will have to ask a separate question

Comment: I suggest using a paste of baking soda and a little bit of water to clear out the acid.  that will probably help expose the problem a bit better.  I don't know much about the PSP's internals, and I can't find any good photos...  if that changes, I'll attempt an answer.